# Why Redux doesn't re-render component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component with `componentDidMount()` method which gets info from server like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getAccount();
}

getAccount = async () => {
    try {
        this.res = await API.get(`account`, {});
        this.props.setData(this.res.data);
    } catch (err) {
        this.props.history.push(`/add`);
    }
}
```

And I have a reducer which store the info:

```
const initialState = {}

const accountReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'SET_ACCOUNT_DATA') {
        return action.data;
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}

export default accountReducer;
```

But my component doesn't re-render after action performed. Why?
My action code is:

```
export const setData = (data) => {
    return {
        type: 'SET_ACCOUNT_DATA',
        data
    }
}
```

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
My map methods are:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({

})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setData: (data) => {
            return dispatch(setData(data));
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Account);
```

Mu action `import` is correct. Checked.

Comment: can you post how you `connect` the component? (and make sure you are using it with a proper `import`)

Comment: `reducer` and `container` are connected each other?

Comment: @Solo if the OP is passing `mapDispatchToProps` in the `connect` (`react-redux`) then the dispatch is implicitly injected. but we do need to see how the OP is using `connect`. if any

Comment: What properties do you have in the state? Is it identical to action.data only? Or is the account data a property in your state only?

Comment: @Sagivb.g updated my question.

Comment: @weibenfalk I don't use `state` in this component

Comment: Can you make sure that you are using the connected component and that the action is actually being triggered and you are passing values from redux store to the component so that it is re-rendered

Comment: You are not binding any values in `mapStateToProps`, so there are no changes

Comment: From you code I see no way your component knows that state has been updated with the data. You need some selector in your `mapStateToProps`, I think.

Comment: But your redux state .. your store ... Youre updating it in the reducer with return action.data .   And your'e saying your'e not using state in the component. Your mapStateToProps are empty. So there's nothing to update in the compontent.

Comment: @Yes you are right! I thought if I trigger dispatch method it will re render. But now it obviously there has to be some state changing in mapStateToProps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In your reducer you probably want to copy origin state and add your changes to it so I think that your reducer should probably looks like:

   ```
   const accountReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
     if (action.type === 'SET_ACCOUNT_DATA') {
       return {...state, data: action.data};
     } else {
       return state;
     }
   }
   ```
2. If your component has `mapStateToProps()`, which is returning empty object then the component is not going to re-render if there is no props/state change... Your `mapStateToProps()` method should maybe look like:

   ```
   const mapStateToProps = state => ({
     data: state.yourReducer.yourDataFromStore
   })
   ```

Comment: The second is the answer. Also thanks to @Davin Tryon

Comment: Thank you! But the first is must-have while you're working with redux :D If you will write reducers like you did, then you will delete your whole store every time, your reducer will return just a new value without the origin state's data :/

Comment: Yes, I will fix it. These was for simplicity to show that I have complete new state from initial.

Answer (score 3):

did you check by putting console.log('state:::',state); inside mapStateToProps() ? Is it called again? 
also can you try this

```
const accountReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'SET_ACCOUNT_DATA') {
        return Object.assign({}, state, {...state, data:action.data });
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}
```

and in your mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>({
  data: state.reducername.data
})
```